# How can I assign a cost to link in mininet in a customized topology

Tags: mininet, google-floodlight

How can I assign a cost to link in mininet? Is it possible to do that? Is this a matter of mininet or something that can be handled by floodlight controller? a brief pointer would be appreciated

THX

Answer (score 0):

The cost of link is a concept usually associated with routing protocols. Mininet itself has no such concept as it current does not have a component that making the route decisions. But up above the Openflow controller that connects to Mininet switches, with proper routing protocols such as OSPF and BGP running as Openflow applications, these protocols can sure assign "cost" or "weight" to the links when deciding the routes (which ultimately translate into flows in Openflow tables of switchs along the route).

Answer (score 0):

The Fast Network Simulation Setup (FNSS) python library might help you out.

There is an example that simulates failures and traffic here [1]. I'm not sure if that topology is compatible with mininet though.

[1] https://github.com/fnss/fnss/blob/master/core/examples/dynamic_topology.py